# How to create a composite index for boolean field in Firebase?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

**Im working with my PHP & Firebase project**

> I have this query code below in my PHP file

```
$query = $ref->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->where("isDeleted", "=", false);
```

This give me a Exception `FailedPreconditionException` and a message `The query requires an index` follow by a composite index link

- I tried to copy & paste the link provided, but nothing happen.
- So I try to create a index in firebase console manually, with the `date as DESC` and `isDeleted as ASC` and nothing happen.

Comment: What's the field name? In the query it is `date` but in your index it is `postDate`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj it's a date I just a made a mistake in posting.

Comment: Have you tried `isDeleted ASC, date ASC`?  `isDeleted` being the first field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of fields in an index does matter. `orderBy()` usually comes after other query constraints like `isDeleted: false` so the database has to order only those filtered entries. You can use the following index:

```
isDeleted ASC
date      ASC
```